# Sort files by hidden value in finder

Tags: macos, finder, macos-big-sur

As simple as that : is there a way to sort files in my finder by hidden value (say all hidden files and directories will be on the bottom of my finder)

Comment: This issue may be better served by migrating it to [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Ok @karolus thank you.